# Where do I put my commanders?

Tags: mass-combat, song-of-ice-and-fire-rpg

I am unsure where to put the commanders on the battlegrid. Do I place them inside a unit, or are they a unit of their own?

My problem with this is, like in the Total War games, that the best way to avoid a quick defeat is to safely place your commander on the edge of the map. The rules don't give a restriction on the range you can give commands.

> Once the battlefield is described, both sides may place their units,
>   commanders, sub-commanders, and attach any heroes they have to
>   units if desired. The defender goes first, placing a unit somewhere on
>   his side of the battlefield. The attacker then places a unit, then the
>   defender, and so on until all units are placed. **Next, the attacker can
>   place his commander and all sub-commanders. The defenders then
>   place their commanders and sub-commanders.** Finally, if either side
>   has heroes, they can, starting with the defender, place them on the
>   battlefield or attach them to units (see Heroes on page 177, and the
>   Attach warfare action on page 185 for details).
>
> *A Song of Ice and Fire Corebook (Step Two: Unit & Leader Placement)*

I would be really grateful to any suggestions and clarifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commanders shouldn't be attached to any unit, unless that unit specifically allows them to retain the ability to issue orders, like **Personal Guards**:

> Special: A commander or sub-commander can attach himself to a
>   personal guard unit and retain the ability to issue orders.

Or **Warships**:

> Special: A commander or sub-commander can attach himself to a
>   warship unit and retain the ability to issue orders.

Otherwise, a commander or sub-commander that attaches himself to a unit, can no longer issue orders to other units in the battlefield until they are detached from it again.

They sit in the back and issue orders to her sub-commanders and units under direct command (think Ramsay Bolton during the Battle of the Bastards). They can join the battlefield if they are attached to a Personal Guard/Warship, or if they renounce command and join battle alongside a unit (see page 185).

**Heroes** on the other hand, will join units and fight alongside them (think John Snow during the Battle of the Bastards). Attaching heroes to units will grant them the same bonus that a commander would, but since they don't issue orders, they take no penalties really.

Comment: If a commander attaches himself to a Personal Guard Unit, will that Unit receive the "Discipline-3; Fighting/Marksmanship +1D" as if it was a hero?

Comment: Yes, you attach characters. They could be commanders, sub-commanders or heroes. That includes player characters or narrator characters, by the way.